# Nutrition plan for weight gain

Tags: nutrition

I have been training for nearly 2 years now. I started first at age 15 in gym for about one month but stopped because I didn't know how to train back then.
When I turned 16 I got dumbbells and only trained biceps at that time. About 7 months later I started doing upper body workout. This year I started doing legs and abs as well.

When I calculated my BMR and TDEE it says I need at least 3200 calories if I want to bulk up or become at least a little bit huge.
I'm an ectomorph, my height is 176cm and my weight is 68kg (145lbs). I was 57 kg one and a half year ago. I'm 17 years old turning 18 next month .

Here's how I eat:

wake up at 11am: eat oatmeal, 4 breads and 2 scrambled eggs.
after 3 hours, meal 2: chapati and chicken.
after 3 hours, meal 3: high calcium milk (I drink all of it) and some almonds like alot of almonds.
after 3 hours, meal 4: chicken and chapati again, I workout about 40 minutes later.
10 minutes after my workout I eat 3 boiled eggs and 1 chicken leg and the hi calcium milk again
After that there is no room left for more food, I feel like throwing up and walk around for like 10 minutes waiting for it to be digested and go to bed.
Bedtime is always at around 10:30pm or 11pm.

This is how I workout:

Monday: Full body workout (except abs) 1 hour and 15-20 minutes
Tuesday: Abs workout, barely 20 minutes
Wednesday: Full body workout (except abs) 1 hour and 15-20 minutes
Thursday: Abs workout, barely 20 minutes
Friday: Full body workout (except abs) 1 hour and 15-20 minutes
Sat&Sunday: rest nothing on those days

I get a little bit fat around my stomach if I don't do cardio workout for like 2 months.

I want to know if my nutrition is good enough.

I have never took any supplements like whey protein or anything because my parent's won't let me have money for it. And well I don't work. I am under 18. I want to know if I am missing something? If it's whey protein tell me which is the best and all the supplements I need for it.

Comment: As soon as I read chapati recommend to read [this  answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4851/3941).

Answer (score 1):

Citing from [the answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4851/3941) I already posted in the comment:

> If you have a typical Indian diet like I used to (though I don't want to typecast or stereotype here), it's probably very carbohydrate-heavy. This means a lot of wheat, rice, potatoes and sugar. […]
>
> Cut down wheat, rice, potatoes and sugar to as little as possible (this can mean just one chapati per meal and no rice, or about two tablespoons of rice), and fill up with fruits, vegetables (which does not mean potatoes) and pulses.

let aside all those calculators (which are highly inaccurate by the way, everybody is different. If you get fattier and don't seem to get more muscles, you are doing something wrong. Learn to look at yourself and adapt your eating habits. You can then use calories to alter your diet.

Protein supplements are in no way a magically gaining muscles. I don't think that you need more protein, your diet seems rather protein rich. On the other hand it seems to lack vegetables and fruits, at least from what I read in your question.

I cannot give you much advice on your specific workout, in an hour or in 20 minutes you can do a really great workout that really strains your muscles, or you could be doing a workout that has little to no effect, consisting of a lot of pauses etc.

- Repeat specific exercises often enough to have an effect. With repeat I don't mean repetitions, which can be, depending on your goals, between a low number for strength or a higher number for endurance, but I am talking about sets. In all cases do between 3 and 5 sets for all exercises, depending on the exercise.
- Variation is important. Your body gets used to specific exercises. So if you are always doing the same exercises, put some variation in them.
  If you lack ideas for exercises:
  [Dumbbell exercises](http://www.dumbbell-exercises.com/exercises/index.html)
  [Exercises sorted by muscle group](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/Directory.html)
- Form is important. You can do a lot of things wrong when working out. With a bad form you wont get the results you are looking for. Try to do exercises slowly, when you use your whole body to throw your weights up, you are doing something wrong. Deload to a point where you can do your exercises in a way that you can stop and hold at any point in the exercises range of motion.
- Contrary to the above, put on more weight if you can. You have to strain your body. If you do 5 reps 5 sets and are not feeling anything afterwards you either are doing to few reps or using not enough weight. (Again, depending on your goals)

You should, even though you are mostly working out with dumbbells, check out [StrongLifts](http://stronglifts.com/). That site gave me some good ideas for my workout plan, even though I am not using barbells.

Comment: thanks bro i will do that and my exercises are good :s but i guess i dnt have anymore weights except for like 30kg total .. 15kg in 1 hand and 15kg in the other hand and well i will try your idea i hope it works :s cuz i m really thinking of juicing myself to get a lil bit huge and lol i dnt get fat i just get a lil bit fat on my abs side if i dnt do cardio lol but its all ok in the end i got biceps triceps and all .. prob is muscles are not growing bigger :/ and so am i

Comment: @RajaSultan You might want to edit your question and add the specific exercises you are doing, this would make helping you a lot easier. Based on the current state of your question only your nutrition can be optimized, and as I said, I only see a lack of vegetables and fruits there.

Comment: ok heres how i do it 
like i said i do full body workout and this is how i workout 
4 sets of 4 minute upper body workout (by 6packshortcuts from yt)
then i do dumbbell curls 44 reps :/ i have low weights so i do more 
and i do hammer curls 44 reps like i said low weights more reps :/ and then i do triceps kickbacks 44 reps and lat raise 22 x
then after them i do leg deadlifts with dumbbells of course Total 88 reps
after it i do pushup's 3x till faliure and 1 clock pushup
and then incline bench press 22 reps and dumbbell fly 22 reps for chest ... this is how i workout for full body