# What foods will help reduce my weight?

Tags: weight-loss, food

I am really obese. I am 5'7" weighing around 93 kg. I should be around 65 kg ideally, i.e I am 28 kg overweight which I want to lose. I have always been fat since my childhood so losing the weight e thing is very tough for me. I've been trying to control what I eat for some days but then I fall back into the same thing. This time I am quite serious about changing my eating habits. What foods can I eat to help reduce my weight?

I know about green tea and lemon, I've been drinking about 2 mugs of it per day. What else will be effective in losing weight? I will be really grateful. All I want is to get rid of this extra weight and curse.

Comment: Please take note from the [faq] that pure nutrition related question are considered off-topic here unless related to your fitness or exercise program. You are welcome to edit your question and provide any supplemental information regarding that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are under a misconception here that I encountered pretty often.

You don't have to eat *more* to reduce your weight, you have to eat *less*. The basics behind it are quite simple.
There may be some foods that help while being on a diet or that reduce your hunger but you shouldn't worry about them too much, you should focus on the main problem and that is:
*you are eating more than you need*.

Your profile says you are from Bangladesh. I am not familiar with the Bangladeshi diet, but I assume it is at least somewhat comparable to the Indian diet and thus I cite from one of my [favorite answers](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4851/3941) in that matter.

> If you have a typical Indian diet like I used to (though I don't want to typecast or stereotype here), it's probably very carbohydrate-heavy. […]
>
> Cut down wheat, rice, potatoes and sugar to as little as possible (this can mean just one chapati per meal and no rice, or about two tablespoons of rice), and fill up with fruits, vegetables (which does not mean potatoes) and pulses. If you do eat grains, try to eat whole grains; no refined wheat flour or maida, or white rice (brown, unpolished rice is preferable). Dairy products are also great: yogurt, milk, buttermilk, paneer, butter and cheese (in moderation, because of cholesterol). Lean meats (if you are non-vegetarian) such as chicken and turkey (and not red meats such as mutton), eggs (no more than one egg yellow/day because of cholesterol), soy etc. are also good things to eat.

Beside from changing your eating habits you should start doing sports, this will support your progress.

Comment: I personally think the other answer deserves more upvotes than it currently has.

Comment: +1
I weight about 84kg (185#s), and I used to weigh as much as 100kg (220#s).  I've always found that I only lose weight if I reduce the amount of food I eat ALONG WITH exercising more.  Fewer heavy carbohydrates, less junk food, less alcohol, and less processed foods always helped.  More crunchy vegetables always helped.  Keeping a journal of what I ate and when I exercised helped, too.  The question does have a slightly wrong premise - there aren't any trick foods that you can add to your diet that cause you to lose weight or not feel hungry.

Comment: @DavidR `there aren't any trick foods that you can add to your diet that cause you to lose weight or not feel hungry.` Yes, there are. Take for instance, sodas; a soda is 20 ounces of nutritionally devoid empty calories that don't fill you up at all. In contrast, you would need to eat two whole apples in order to get the same amount of calories as you got from the soda. So in this case, the "trick food" is anything that is a nutritious, healthy, whole food.

Comment: @Moses the problem is that there are some people who think that they can continue drinking the soda, add the apples and lose weight because the apples are healthy.

Comment: @Moses -  :)  yes, good point.  Natural "whole foods" and vegetables are significantly better than sugared sodas and junk food.  I only meant that you couldn't just add some sort of supplement (a tea, fish oil, etc) to an otherwise unhealthy diet, and expect to see a benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the replies ..I didn't mention, i have reduced a lot taking regular foods, so all my question was what can i take by reducing regular diet and as supplementary with it ..By the way thanks for all replies. So, i found Carbohydrates are the reason for fat cells and all i need to find a diet leaving carbohydrates. Do you know any plan like this?

Answer (score 5):

It all comes down to body chemistry.

Why did you deposit more fat than the average human?

To deposit a lot of fat you had to eat a lot more than your body used up as energy. Fat cells became supersaturated at some point and new cells grew. You probably have more fat cells than a lean person, so you have to face the fact that for the rest of your life you'll be more prone to maintain your current weight, because those cells want to accumulate fat. You also may have different brain chemistry, that doesn't repel food once you've eaten enough.

Some of the most frequent misconceptions is that eating fatty foods you get fat. It's not quite like that.
Actually, eating carbohydrates (complex forms of glucose, that eventually get broken down into glucose by different enzymes) increases the sugar levels in your blood, which triggers the release of insulin to take care of that glucose. Insulin acts as a trigger to get more fat into fat cells. **So if you eat carbohydrates, and eat a lot of food, you will get fat.**

My wife sat on a diet that is really working for her. She eliminated all carbohydrates from the diet (no fruits or vegetables, no sugar, no bread, no cereals, just some milk products with low amount of lactose, a lot of fish and meat). Now this isn't quite healthy since we need a lot of vitamins from fruits and vegetables, but when it's short-term, and with dietary supplements, it's bearable. She lost quite a lot the first few days. **Point is that carbohydrates should be reduced in order to get thinner.**

Anyway, **you need to count the energetic value of the food you consume**. An average active male needs about 2000-2500 kcal per day. Want to get thin? Reduce to about 1500 kcal per day, take on strength training. Strength training increases muscle mass, and more muscles demand more energy, so once you get into an athletic shape, you can revert to your normal diet, as long as you keep training.

Ultimately, **there are no food products that make you lose weight**. There are food products you can reduce or eliminate from your diet, which will help you lose weight. Some acquaintances of mine have resorted to some herbal teas that help you lose weight, but now they have serious intestinal problems because of them. Others use other kinds of poisons to damage their bodies which eventually makes them thinner. Some use parasites. Whatever. If you want to be healthy, don't use any of these "easy" methods to "instantly" lose weight. They're always crippling the body.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer it really helped, i have reduced a lot of taking carbohydrates that i like i.e Rice and Wheat..so, fruits also have Carbohydrates right ? So, is there any diet available without carbohydrates fulfilling body requirements?