# How to reduce my obesity?

Tags: bellyfat, burn-fat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am overweight and need to reduce?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/i-am-overweight-and-need-to-reduce)

I am a 22 year old male, I weight about 60.5kg and I am nearly 5 ft 7" tall.

I'm from India so I eat a lot of spicy and oily food with more calories.
I used to eat the same diet since my high school but now my belly has enlarged a lot.

How do I reduce my obesity and fat to reduce my belly? What other things should I do to increase my fitness and get healthier?

Comment: How tall are you? 60.5 doesn't sound obese to me. Check out this [answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4851/3941) which talks about the Indian cuisine. Also please add what exercises you are doing (or capable/willing to do), also please check out the [faq].

Comment: Hi grv.giit, and I grant you a warm welcoming to my site.  Thanks for your question.  You mention that you are obese, but you also say your weight is 60.5kg, which doesn't seem to be that heavy.  Could you please also mention your height if you know it?

Comment: @grv.giit, if you are interested in nutrition questions, please subscribe to this group.  If enough people show interest, the site will be up and running soon enough:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Comment: Thanks for all the support guys. I am nearly 5 ft 7". Actually, My height is fair enough but my belly has just bulged out. Due to this, I just feel my height has shortened a bit more...

Comment: You're BMI index based on the data you have given is 20.9.  This means you are in the normal weight range, boarding on underweight.

Comment: Have you considered the possibilities of a aerophagia, a hernia, or protein deficiency?  Both these things could cause bulging abdomen.

Comment: Chris, Would my belly get enlarge enough if I have protein deficiency?

Comment: Probably not.  There are multiple causes of bulging abdomen, some of which are life threatening, such as heart disease.  Is there a local physician you can visit who can examine you at low cost?  Is your belly always bulging, or are there times when it is worse (morning or night)?  Does your abdomen ever bulge after eating certain foods?

Comment: [BMI is not an accurate measurement](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/10002/3941) to determine the health of an individual but a statistical measurement to determine the fitness level of a group. If you want know if you are overweight [check your body fat percentage](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/2592/3941) or take a look in the mirror.

Comment: @Informaficker, looking in the mirror won't tell you if you have a leaky bowel causing bloating.  Sometimes people think they are fat from the mirror, when actually they have a serious medical condition and aren't overweight.  When someone has a BMI of almost underweight, and they think they look obese, I would be concerned about a potential medical condition, regardless of wehther BMI is a statistic or not.

Comment: If you think that someone might have a serious condition, stop right there, tell them what you think and that they should see a doctor. Asking for medical advice is off topic here as is giving medical advice. 20.9 ist not even close to underweight: _"a BMI of 18.5 to 25 may indicate optimal weight"_ ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index#Usage))

Comment: Not everyone has access to a doctor.  < 18.5 is underweight.  A BMI of 20 is certainly much closer to 18.5 than to 25.  And certainly very far from the "obese" range.  Do you not see the problem here?

Comment: @grv.giit, could you be pregnant?

Comment: @Chris males cannot get pregnant. (_hint: check the name_)

Comment: That's correct I too think males can't be pregnant lol!!

Comment: @Informaficker, I'm not from India and I don't presume to know what is a Male name and what is a Female name.  My comment was also made in humour which you obviously don't have a sense for.

Comment: @grv.giit, I'm glad you understood my humour good man.

Comment: I liked your temperament friend not a problem at all :)

Comment: Hey, I just forgot to tell my age. I am 23 male from India. ha ha ha !

Comment: can anybody suggest me on taking a new year resolution on my health and fitness? I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Well exercise is always good.  30 minutes of continuous exercise per day is recommended for good health.  My resolution is therefore to walk/jog for a period of 30 minutes each day.  Each day I will try and jog more and walk less.

Comment: This may be a good start.  I recommend a very basic new years resolution.  Once you can do this for 21 days, continue to do so, and add additional components to your "health and fitness" regime, such as small diet changes etc.    Small changes at a time are best as they are easier to stick to.

Comment: Please don't forget to join this site:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Comment: Yeah, I will make sure to join the site. A thumps up from me ..!!

Comment: @grv.giit I edited your question to include the information you mentioned in the comments. Please try to edit missing information into the question instead of posting them as comments. If you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert them or edit it again.

Comment: sure, I will do that and keep in my mind friend :)

Comment: yes similar to that as I am also in IT field but my weight is around 61 kg.

Comment: @grv.giit that does not really make a difference, as the answer will likely be the same, only that you don't have to do as much to reach the same goal, since you are closer. If you spot other differences, please make them clear in your question.

Comment: @Informaficker:- I also encounter frequent urination is this a symptom of Diabetes ?

Comment: @grv.giit Some [symptoms of Diabetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes#Signs_and_symptoms) are explained on Wikipedia. Please go and see a doctor, this site is not supposed to give health related advice. Only thing I can tell you here is that diabetes is rather common in Indian males (at least thats what I read). So again **see a professional**.

Comment: Ok, enough chit-chat, please move the discussion to chat. These comments will be cleaned up in due time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BMI is 20.9, which is considered optimal-to-low.  However, BMI is far from a perfect measurement of health, and is mostly useful for diagnosing extreme under or over weight. In your case, if you're visibly pudgy/fat, you probably lack lean body mass and have a high body fat percentage.  For someone of normal BMI, body fat percentage, waist circumference and [waist-to-hip ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waist%E2%80%93hip_ratio) are likely to be more useful measures.

Since your abdomen is thick, you probably have a lot of [visceral fat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visceral_fat#Abdominal_fat), which is the absolute worst kind of fat to have.  It's one of the main risk factors for metabolic syndrome and diabetes.

As @informaticker mentioned in the comments, the fat loss advice is basically the same as for an obese/overweight person, but since you (probably) lack lean mass, strength training is especially important.  You probably don't need to lose weight: you need to gain muscle/lean mass and lose fat.  I'd suggest a high protein diet