# Will this workout help to reduce my weight?

Tags: running, weight-loss, workout-routines, dumbbells, treadmill

I am a man weighing 81kg, 6ft 2inch, 25yrs and I've been going to the gym for the last two months. I don't have a gym trainer here (office gyms). My workouts are as follows:

```
Day 1
Warm up:
Running on treadmill (2km - max 15mins)
Running on Elliptical (2km - 8min) 
Abdominal Crunch (3sets - 15reps)
Biceps training (3sets - 12reps, 7.5kg)
Push ups (3sets - 10reps)

Day 2 (alternate day)
Warm up:
Running on treadmill (2km - max 15mins)
Running on Elliptical (2km - 8min) 
Abdominal Crunch (3sets - 15reps)
Triceps training (3sets - 12reps, 7.5kg)
Chest training (3sets)
Bench Press (3sets - 10reps, 20kg)
Push ups (3sets - 10reps)
```

I spend nearly 90 mins in gym.
I used to do all above exercise with certain rest periods and usually on Sundays I don't go to gym.

I want to reduce my weights to 75 kg. Do these exercise helps me?

Comment: I edited your question. Please make sure next time before you submit a text that the formating is uniform and looks like you intended it to look like. If you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert them or edit again.

Comment: What does your diet look like? If you want to lose weight, changing your diet is key.

Comment: I usually take a average diet .Morning - 2 piece of Carbohydrate cake (chappathi) or a Rice cake(dosai).Lunch- Medium amount of rice,vegetables(Mostly cabbage,potatoes,cauliflower), Sometimes evening-fruits (orange,apple) or snacks! & Dinner (again some rice ,with salads ( carrot), eggs(not daily). And Twice in a week I used to take Chicken as sidedish for dinner time.

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to lose weight? It's possible that you'll just end up trading fat for muscle, and staying approximately the same weight. Would that be acceptable to you? 81kg isn't heavy for your height.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4851/3941), it gives a good idea about the common pitfalls of the Indian diet.

Comment: Really !!! But I get a little belly. My friend who is exactly same height of me weighs 75kg & looks lean compared to me.We Both used to play for our college basketball team 2 years before. He used to jump more height compared to me." I mean he can catch the Basketball Ring & float ,But I can Only touch it for few seconds:( ""

Comment: thanks for your comments :) @Informaficker . . .But here i don't have any other option to eat. I'm working in a remote place & I have to depend only on "SODEXO" for my survival. Can I follow these work outs in my Gym ? or Will it cause any harmful effects? Since I don't have a personalised gym trainer , & most of my friends confuse me regarding the work outs ,I'm in a doubtfull condition . Help..

Comment: Guys ,one last question. Is it good to lift weights (like building biceps) & to run on treadmill in the same day. Some people says that running will cause to loose the Fat & lifting weights will add some extra weight (Kg's) in our Body..Is that true??  @Informaficker & Kate

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, if you want to lose weight, adjust your diet. I wont delve into this, but focus on diverse, protein rich meals. Try to bring the carbohydrates (wheat, sugar, rice, potatoes) down a bit, if possible.

Cardio exercises like running on a Treadmill or Elliptical are good for your endurance, but as they drain a lot of energy you might consider to move them to the end of your workout.
I would only do one of both on each given day, as the movement is quite similar and I doubt there is any benefit switching the machines compared to doing one exercise longer. If you have a stationary bike, it might be advantageous to switch, as the movement is different.

You weight-exercises look a bit unplanned to me, I think you are using machines here mostly, but some of the lifts look like you have a barbell or dumbbells available. I'd recommend you to look into free weights lifting programms such as [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/) or [StrongLifts](http://stronglifts.com/). They only use a small set of barbell exercises, but as those exercises are compound lifts you will engage your whole body doing these.

You don't even have to use the gym every day, only three days are enough to build muscle. If you work out too often you risk overtraining.
I know how compelling it is to work out every day, especially when you've just begun and can't wait to lose those pounds. But again, losing weight comes from the right diet, building muscles comes from exercising. And to build muscles you need to rest.

By the way: you complain about belly-fat and do crunches, note there is no such thing as [spot reduction](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Myths.html). Just saying this, because a lot of people who have belly-fat think the abdominal muscles and the abdominal fat are somewhat related.

Comment: There is a lot of information regarding all those topics that has been asked on here before.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback @informaficker...I hope it will help me a lot :) I used to play basketball during my childhood! But for the last 2 years it is not possible to continue my game. Due to some changes in my diet, I think I have gained some belly fat!. my BMI is 23.5 , I know it should be around 19 to 25 & I feel to have it around 21 or 22. ;) .so want to reduce those 5kgs. Recently got a info that lifting heavy weights will tend to decrease testosterone hormone. Is that true?

Comment: @Ajay - Welcom to Physical Fitness! I've converted your previous "answer" to a comment on the answer it seems to be a response to. If you have further follow-up questions, we'd love to answer them in an entirely new question. If you have any questions about this site and how it typically operates, feel free to check out our [about page](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/about) or, once you have 20 reputation, join us in the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com).